# How do I remove CSS comments use javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, css-loader

```css
var css = `
.test {
  background-image: url(//www.google.com/image/1.png); // goole iamge
}
@font-face {
    font-display: auto;
    font-family: vant-icon;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff2?t=1694918397022)
            format("woff2"),
        url("https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff?t=1694918397022")
            format("woff");
}
/**
  I‘am commonts
*/
`
```

Above code that I want to remove all the commoents. but it is too hard, becasue the code hava keywrok that like `https://`, `url(//xxx)`. How to resolve this problem?

**This is the incorrect way**

```
var re2 = /\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(?<=[^:])\/\/.*|^\/\/.*/g; // incorrect

// this code is incorrect
```

**Expect**

CSS code

```css
.test {
  background-image: url(//www.google.com/image/1.png);
}
@font-face {
    font-display: auto;
    font-family: vant-icon;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff2?t=1694918397022)
            format("woff2"),
        url("https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff?t=1694918397022")
            format("woff");
}
```

This code is correct. the `clean-css` is work, but how to use the simple way?

Comment: Why not use the clean-css package given that it's well tested and maintained?

Comment: FYI `// goole iamge` is an **invalid CSS comment**. Valid in SCSS.

Comment: Thanks, I have been resove this promblem. Using 'clean-css' AST module to finished it。

https://github.com/WangZhenHao/wxmini-plugin-webpack/blob/master/src/lib/clean-css/index.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **valid CSS** comments and preserve formatting, you could use this regex:

```js
const css = `.test {
  background-image: url(//www.google.com/image/1.png);
}
@font-face {
    font-display: auto;
    font-family: vant-icon; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff2?t=1694918397022)
            format("woff2"),
        url("https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff?t=1694918397022")
            format("woff");
}
/**
  Some comment
*/ body {
  color: /* some nice
color */ gold;
}`;

console.log(css.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//gsm, ""));
```

And if you want to also remove some single-line comments like `// Some comment` which would make it more a **SCSS syntax** you could use (untested):

```js
const css = `.test {
  background-image: url(//www.google.com/image/1.png); // goole iamge
}
@font-face {
    font-display: auto;
    font-family: vant-icon; ////// blah!!!
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff2?t=1694918397022)
            format("woff2"),
        url("https://at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_2553510_kfwma2yq1rs.woff?t=1694918397022")
            format("woff");
}
/**
  Some comment
*/ body {
  color: /* some nice
color */ gold;
}`;

console.log(css.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\/|\/+[^/)]*?$/gsm, ""));
```

And here's an in-depth explanation and playground (in case I missed something): [Demo on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4un4qp/1)

Comment: Thanks, I have been resove this promblem. Using 'clean-css' AST module to finished it。

https://github.com/WangZhenHao/wxmini-plugin-webpack/blob/master/src/lib/clean-css/index.js